# Showing GraphQL Subscription results in GraphiQL

Tags: java, graphql, vert.x

I am trying to get a GraphQL subscription working with Java/Vert.x and to have the results shown in GraphiQL. I see all the System.out.println statements in the console, but GraphiQL is not displaying any results because the server is generating an 'Internal Server Error' message.

Schema:

```
type Subscription {
    test: String
}
```

Vert.x Verticle

```
private RuntimeWiring getRuntimeWiring() {
  return new RuntimeWiring()
    .type("Subscription", builder -> builder
      .dataFetcher("test", getTestDataFetcher()))
    .build();
}

private VertxDataFetcher<Publisher<String>> getTestDataFetcher() {
  return new VertxDataFetcher<>((env, future) -> future.complete(doTest()));
}

private Publisher<String> doTest() {
  AtomicReference<Subscription> ar = new AtomicReference<>();
  Observable<String> obs = Observable.just("Hello");
  Publisher<String> pub = obs.toFlowable(BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
  pub.subscribe(new Subscriber<String>() {
    @Override  
    public void onSubscribe(Subscription s) {
      System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE");
      ar.set(s);
      s.request(1);
    }
    @Override  
    public void onNext(String s) {
      System.out.println("NEXT="+s);
      ar.get().request(1);
    }
    @Override  
    public void onError(Throwable t) {
      System.out.println("ERROR");
    }
    @Override  
    public void onComplete(){
      System.out.println("COMPLETE");
    }
  }
  return pub;
}
```

If I run the subscription using GraphiQL and look on my vert.x servers console, the output on the console is:

```
SUBSCRIBE
NEXT=Hello
COMPLETE
```

The GraphiQL output window says "Internal Server Error" and is sent a 500 error code from the server

If I modify the DataFetcher to exactly what is shown at the bottom of the first link, I also receive "Internal Server Error".

```
private DataFetcher<Publisher<String>> getTestDataFetcher() {
  return env -> doTest();
}
```

I do not see any stack traces for the 500 error in the vertx console.  So maybe this is a bug?

Sidenote  - If I try using a CompletionStage as shown below (based off the bottom of the 2nd link) I get an error message saying 'You data fetcher must return a publisher of events when using graphql subscriptions'

```
private DataFetcher<CompletionStage<String>> getTestDataFetcher() {
  Single<String> single = Single.create(emitter -> { 
    new Thread(()-> {
      try {
        emitter.onSuccess("Hello");
      } catch(Exception e) {
        emitter.onError(e);
      }
    }).start();
  )};
  return environment -> single.to(SingleInterop.get());
}
```

I have used the following sources as references to get this far:

- https://www.graphql-java.com/documentation/v9/subscriptions/
- https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-graphql/java/

Comment: Subscriptions are not supported yet. You might wanna keep an eye on https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-web/pull/1325 which will add support soon.

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I've been following that for a while now after this post. Wish I would've found out about it sooner though :|